# How can I extract data from specific cells on a specific trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, scripting

I am being asked to make a Google spreadsheet do the following and I have no idea how to make this happen:

I work at a car dealership where we track live sales on a shared Google spreadsheet.  They go on the sheet when the deal starts and get removed (deleted) when the sale is finalized.  Each line item (deal) has a drop down cell (column G) with different deal statuses.  One of the statuses is "Missing Docs" meaning the sales team did not provide all documents necessary to generate the contracts.  We want to track who runs high rates of missing docs, so we're thinking that when "Missing Docs" is selected on a row, the script will automatically run and snapshot the Customer Name (column A), Stock Number (column B), Sales Person Name (column D) and Issue Notes (column I), then drop that data into another worksheet to be saved a historic data record.

Any help building a script that would perform this function would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getMissingDocs() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("outputSheetName");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => r[6] == "Missing Docs").map(r => [r[0],r[1],r[3],r[8]]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.getRange(1,1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == "Missing Docs") {
    getMissingDocs();
  }
}
```

If you have other onEdit functions you will need to integrate them together into one function or another option is to rename it and use an installable onEdit function.

Comment: Happy to try that!  I don't see where the script tells the system where to write the data to, like another sheet.  But maybe I just don't understand the script language...?

Comment: Are you not the one that added the google apps script tag

Comment: Oh, I'm not. I added the other three tags. Not sure where that one came from.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: You said you didn't know what the language was

Comment: Oh I guess it was player0 that added it

Comment: Yeah... I'm like an advanced average user of spreadsheets.  I've put scripts together based off stuff I've searched on Google but it really is a foreign language to me.  I just super appreciate help from people like you who take the time to set this stuff up with me.  I put in your code and got this error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 8, file "Missing Docs")

Comment: It did not find and `Missing Docs` in column 7.  I just tested it and it works

Comment: So did you get the right column or perhaps you did not add the sheet name  or the output sheet name

Comment: So weird, it WORKS NOW!!!  Woo hoo!!!!!  You are awesome.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243834/discussion-between-anthony-ianucilli-and-cooper).